# Уникальные номер

Tags: android

Есть ли на телефоне какой-нибудь уникальный, общедоступный набор символов (Общедоступный, в плане что бы можно было взять его используя Android API).

Например серия телефона или что-то ещё. Нужно что бы для каждого телефона в мире эти цифры/буквы были разные.

**Для чего это нужно:**

В моём приложение данных сохраняются в SharedPreferens. BlueStacks (Эмулятор андроида на пк) имеет функцию полного копирования системы/опр.приложения (Включая все его сохранения). У меня получилось достать APK файл с сохранениями и тем самым, вышел своеобразный взлом приложения. Закрыть эту дыру я решил тем, что буду в SharedPreferens сохранять уникалный набор цифр/символов и при каждом включении приложения проверять: соответствуют ли сохранёные данные с уникальным набором цифр/символов которые забиты в телефоне.

Надеюсь вопрос разложил нормально)

Comment: Раньше можно было (с некоторыми ограничениями) использовать IMEI, начиная с 10 Андроида уже нет. Но есть какие-то моменты от гугла https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: Уже нашел оовет - Android ID. Получить можно так: ```Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);```. Есть некоторые нюансы, так-что тем, кто зашёл на этот вопрос в поисках ответа лучше погуглить и убедиться, что Android ID больше всего подходит вам

Comment: @antoshka, ответы - в ответы.